# Ignore Varargs Warnings In Javac

Tags: ant, javac

I want to escalate the missing serialversionUID warning to an error and fail my build when it occurs in javac.

I have added the following to my ant task:

```
  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:serial"/>
  <compilerarg value="-Werror"/>
```

However, the build also fails with varargs warnings:

```
non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
```

I tried changing the javac task to

```
  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:-varargs"/>
  <compilerarg value="-Xlint:serial"/>
  <compilerarg value="-Werror"/>
```

However, it made no difference. How do I make the compiler ignore these warnings and only fail on the serialversionUID?

I am using Ant 1.9.4 and tried with Javac 1.6u37, 1.7u79 and 1.8u92

Example class:

```
package com.stackoverflow.compiler;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Main implements Serializable {

    public static void foo(Object... args) {
        System.out.println("Test foo");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // is args supposed to be an array of objects
        // or the only element in an array?
        foo(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the question is about `javac`, but let me still mention that `ecj` can be configured to meet your requirement: simply say `-err:serial` on the command line.

With that option this source file

```
public class Serial implements java.io.Serializable {}
```

will trigger this compiler output

```
----------
1. ERROR in /tmp/Serial.java (at line 1)
        public class Serial implements java.io.Serializable {}
                     ^^^^^^
The serializable class Serial does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long
----------
1 problem (1 error)
```

Other warnings are not affected by that option. In particular, you could complete suppress the varargs warning by adding `-warn:-varargsCast`. This isn't necessary because a warning will never let your build fail. But if you really don't want to see this even as a warning, the full command line would look like this:

```
ecj -err:serial -warn:-varargsCast Main.java
```

See the [JDT FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT/FAQ#Can_I_use_JDT_outside_Eclipse_to_compile_Java_code.3F) for using ecj in automated builds, incl. ant.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. It also outputs "Type String[] of the last argument to method foo(Object...) doesn't exactly match the vararg parameter type. Cast to Object[] to confirm the non-varargs invocation, or pass individual arguments of type Object for a varargs invocation."

Comment: @opticyclic The point is that with `ecj` you can independently fine tune different diagnostics to warning or error. The diagnostic you show is classified as a warning by default. I'll update my answer to cover how to completely suppress that warning.

Comment: You are right. I confused the output as I had two examples in the same class.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the warning you have is not related to the `-Xlint:varargs` option

According to [javac reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html#BHCJCABJ) the varargs option for `-Xlint`:

> Warns about unsafe usages of variable arguments (varargs) methods, **in particular, those that contain non-reifiable arguments**

The documentation says that the following code:

```
public class ArrayBuilder {
  public static <T> void addToList (List<T> listArg, T... elements) {
    for (T x : elements) {
      listArg.add(x);
    }
  }
}
```

should produce the warning:

`warning: [varargs] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type T`

The actual warning I get (using javac 1.8.0_65) is:

`warning: [unchecked] Possible heap pollution from parameterized vararg type T`

(i.e **unchecked** instead of **varargs**)

The warning you got can be caused by code like this:

```
public static void foo(Object... args) {...}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // is args supposed to be an array of objects 
    // or the only element in an array?
    foo(args);
}
```

That warning went away only using `-Xlint:none` option, but then `-Xlint:serial` does nothing. So it seems what you want is not possible.